# How to ensure model dimensions in Keras Autoencoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to generate an autoencoder architecture with Keras, but I'm having problems ensuring that the dimensions from the first and last layers remain the same; I must take into account that the input shape is not a squared matrix (and It can change from time to time)

How can I create a model for an arbitrary input shape?
Here is what I got so far:

```py
def create_autoencoder(input_shape):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Input(shape=input_shape))

    # Encoder
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu" , padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding='same'))  
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

    # Decoder
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding='same'))  
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation="sigmoid", padding='same'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

    return model
```

If I have X_train as a numpy array of shape `(n_samples, 5, 128)` I'd call it like this:

```py
model = create_autoencoder(input_shape=(5, 128, 1))
model.summary()
```

This model doesn't conserve the final layer dimensions of `(None, 5, 128, 1)` but instead returns `(None, 8, 128, 1)`

**EDIT:** I notice this only happens if the input shape doesn't have even numbers, so for example, `input_shape=(6, 128, 1)` works fine

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 5, 128, 32)        320       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 3, 64, 32)        0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 3, 64, 64)         18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 2, 32, 64)        0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 2, 32, 64)         36928     
                                                                 
 up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D  (None, 4, 64, 64)        0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 64, 32)         18464     
                                                                 
 up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling  (None, 8, 128, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 128, 1)         289       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 74,497
Trainable params: 74,497
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Training this model
`model.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=100)`
would result in this error:

```py
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5 and 8 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](IteratorGetNext:1, binary_crossentropy/Log)' with input shapes: [?,5,128], [?,8,128].
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the downsampling and upsampling created by the MaxPooling and UpSampling layers, you should always try to make your your input a multiple of the stride. Since a stride of 2 is very common, most folks use powers of 2 (2, 4, 8, ..., 128, 256, ...) I'm actually surprised hat it works for an input shape of `(6, 128, 1)` since 6 is not a power of two.

So what to do if a data dimension is smaller than a power of two? If possible, try to reshape the data size since this is by far the easiest approach. Otherwise, you are going to have to pad data to make the dimension the nearest multiple of the stride above the current size and then you need to mask out all the values that were padded when calculating the loss.

A separate observation, your encoder will have a very poor compression in the latent space because the redundancies in the spatial domain are being preserved albeit at a coarser scale. The right way to do this is to flatten the output of the last conv/maxpool layer and pass it through a dense/linear layer which projects this into your desired latent space dimension. On the decoder side, you then start with a dense layer which you then reshape into the exact same dimensions as the output of the last conv/maxpool layer in the encoder, and then proceed by the layers as you have them. Also, I would make the last decoder conv layer have at least a 3x3 kernel otherwise you'll see blocking artifacts from the last UpSampling layer.